# Why do only a few English demonyms have a -man suffix?

Tags: etymology, english

Several English demonyms ([*Englishman*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=Englishman)) are compound words ending in [*-man*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=man), but most are not ([*Greek*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=Greek)).

The vast majority of *-man* demonyms refer to England and close neighbors: *Frenchman, Irishman, Scotsman, Welshman, Dutchman, Norseman.* Because of this, I thought the compound might be an early form that stopped being productive, but [*Dutchman*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=Dutchman) and [*Chinaman*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=Chinaman) are more recent – and *Greek* dates to Old English *Grecas.*

*Scotsman* is unusual in that the non-compound form *Scot* is also acceptable. *Chinaman* is unusual in that it compounds *China+man* instead of *Chinese+man.*

Are there etymological rules or patterns behind these differences? Are there parallels in other languages?

Comment: This came out of a discussion of gendered demonyms on ELU.SE: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113774/why-do-only-a-few-english-demonyms-indicate-gender

Comment: I've always wondered about this myself.

Comment: I think that demonyms with "man" are on their way out because many English speakers have come to view the use of "man" to mean "human" as sexist.   Here in Washington State USA, I rarely hear "man" demonyms and never see them in current newspapers.  Also, "Chinaman" is not only morphologically unusual--it is also considered offensive.  I don't know if these two facts are related.

Comment: @JamesGrossmann I suspect that _Chinaman_ became offensive simply because too many Americans used it to mean “worthless Asian.” There's some [discussion on the Straight Dope forum](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=517299). As for _-man_: Ironically, _man_ didn't mean “male” until Middle English, when _wif+man_ “woman-person” become common usage.

Comment: The comment about geographical proximity seems reasonable.But in Welsh you have the opposite, where you have irregular forms _Cymro_ for 'Welshman' and _Saes_ for "Englishman" but then regular forms for _Ffrancwr_ 'Frenchman', _Archentwr_ 'Argentinian', _Americanwr_ 'American' (where _-wr_ means 'man') for those further away lands.